# Is it possible to insert the meta tag X-UA_compatible before the code generated by cfajaximport?

Tags: html, coldfusion, http-headers, coldfusion-9, x-ua-compatible

I have this meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
```

that I need to put just before the  tag. But I have also further in the cf code this:

```
<cfajaximport scriptsrc="cfscripts/" csssrc="cfscripts/ajax/">
```

that generates a whole bunch of instruction in the source code of the page, like this:

```
script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */_cf_loadingtexthtml="<img alt=' '             src='/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/resources/cf/images/loading.gif'/>";
_cf_contextpath="";
_cf_ajaxscriptsrc="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax";
_cf_jsonprefix='//';
_cf_clientid='34E7CEE60001694E2BAD23DBDEE4C6DE';/* ]]> */
```

That make my meta tag not usefull anymore.

Is there a way to oblige ColdFusion to put this tag at the very beginning to the head ?

Thank you in advance,
Michel

Comment: The order of the metatags in your page head shouldn't make any difference.  If that javascript is causing a problem with the X-UA-Compatible metatag, moving the metatag further up is unlikely to fix your problem.

Comment: Hi duncan, you're not right, on this page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx) is it wel written that: 'The X-UA-Compatible header isn't case sensitive; however, it must appear in the header of the webpage (the HEAD section) before all other elements except for the title element and other meta elements.' and this can be found in other topics of stackovreflow too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify X-UA-Compatible as a real HTTP header (instead of using HTML's http-equiv in a meta tag), which will ensure it applies before any HTML/JS is output.

The simplest way is probably to set it at the front-end web server level - how to do this depends on your web server (e.g. [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html), [IIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753133%28v=WS.10%29.aspx), [nginx](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/nginx-send-custom-http-headers/), etc), or you can use [cfheader](http://cfdocs.org/cfheader) to do it with CF:

```
<cfheader name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
```

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for your answer. I tried the cf solution as we have more than one application and cannot change something in apache :). Using cfheader gives me the document mode of ie9 as ie9standards instead of ie7standards. Only the browser mode stay in compat view. It is already an improvement, thanks, Michel